# MissingSessionUser Exception in Sockjs with Spring

Tags: java, spring, header, stomp, spring-websocket

I am trying to make a chat application with WebSocket. I am able to send a message to all the connected clients, and now I am trying to send a message to a single user.

script:

```
var socket = new SockJS("server endpoint");
```

subscribe:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chat', renderMessage);
```

connection:

```
stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", connectCallback, errorCallback);
```

where it's sent:

```
stompClient.send("/app/addMessage", {}, jsonstr);
```

and in my spring config:

```
<websocket:message-broker
        application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
            <websocket:sockjs />
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
        <websocket:client-inbound-channel>
            <websocket:interceptors>
                <bean class="com.websocket.interceptor.ConnectionInterceptor" />
            </websocket:interceptors>
        </websocket:client-inbound-channel>
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

method that is trying to send to a single user:

```
@MessageMapping("/addMessage")
public void addChatMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage,
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor,Principal principal) throws Exception {
    chatMessageList.add(chatMessage);
    //trying to output the user but returns null
    System.out.println(headerAccessor.getUser());
    //returns null
    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    //not sending to the current user 
    template.convertAndSendToUser("user", "/topic/chat", chatMessageList);
}
```

and in my browser, I tried to open the console and I can see that the header is `undefined`:

```
connected to server undefined
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/chat
```

stack trace:

```
Oct 13, 2014 9:53:36 AM org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler processHandlerMethodException
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.java:43)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:451)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:363)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:80)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:409)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:345)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How can I send to a single user? How can I get all the headers in my `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor`? And how headers actually work?

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe you need to use `"/user/"` prefix to make it recognized by Spring `UserDestinationMessageHandler`. So the code will be :

`stompClient.subscribe('user/topic/chat', renderMessage);`

See [Spring Websocket user destinations.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination)